# Windows phone 7 keyboard size

Tags: windows-phone-7, keyboard, resize, size

I want to resize the page when the keyboard appears on the screen.

I was looking for any clue all day but I can't find anything.

In my case. I want to have full page TextBox and some buttons under it.

```
<Grid x:Name="RootLayout" >

    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer Margin="0" >
            <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="698" Width="480"/>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <Canvas x:Name="RootMenu" Margin="0,1,0,0" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

I use to thing that the first row will change its size automatically, but it doesn't happening.

Please help me.

///// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

I'm going to dislike this OS! Proposed solution is not good at all. When the keyboard is visible then I can not scroll it down.

Lets say I want just simple TextBox to let users write something. But it is impossible !!

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/icons/appbar.check.rest.png" Text="aplay"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>

<Grid x:Name="RootLayout" >
    <ScrollViewer>
        <TextBox  Text="TextBox" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a way to know for sure if the SIP is displayed. [Jaime Rodriguez has a post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2010/11/05/guessing-if-the-sip-is-visible-in-a-windows-phone-application.aspx) showing how to make a fairly reliable guess of this.

If you want to have "buttons" that are always displayed then the best, and only reliable, way to do this is to use the ApplicationBar.

Comment: However in one note it looks like texbox changes its width.

Comment: I can set page height for static vale when textbox focus event fires, but is it good solution? Is it going to work over all devices?

Comment: Setting a specific height is almost certain to have issues when the small screen devices come out. If you can live with having to readjust to accout for them when they are released you could consider this.

Comment: Performing the action on textbox focus assumes that there will be a SIP. For devices with a physical keyboard this MAY not be the case. (orientation and if the keyboard is slid out (if appropriate) can affect if the SIP is displayed)

Comment: OneNote is one of the native apps and therefore has access to APIs that are not available to us. :(

Comment: I'm going to dislike this OS!

Comment: +1 Hi Michal, it's worth considering this is a v1 product. As such there are going to be areas that can use improvement. I think we all agree this is one such area and I would encourage you to post your experiences in Microsoft suggestions forum and/or open a Connect ticket (vs/wpdt). Matt's coverage of your topics is accurate, I recommend accepting this solution. Ps - if your users need to be able to input text larger than the size of your textbox there are challenges here too. I recommend reviewing that and including your observations in any comments you write to MSFT.

Comment: Could any one tell me what is the meaning of `SIP` i know its related to keyboard but what exactly it stands for

Comment: @InderKumarRathore "SIP" is short for "Soft Input Panel" - it's the on-screen keyboard