# How do you find the screen position of a control in silverlight on WP7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

How do you find the screen position of a control in silverlight on WP7?

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you know how it's positioned (eg in a `Canvas`) there may be a more appropriate way to do things, but in general, you can use `UIElement.TransformToVisual` to convert between the control's and the global coordinate system:

```
var transform = myControl.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual)
var offset = transform.Transform(new Point(0,0))
```

Be sure that the control has undergone layout before trying to do this, if you do it too early the error messages are generally unhelpful.

(MSDN suggests the method is present in WP7, I don't have the SDK installed to test)

Comment: That is correct for all the cases I have tried, except for when the keyboard is being displayed. Is there a way to know what the position is as the keyboard is entering and exiting?

Comment: No, the keyboard is part of the OS and it seems like the OS can just shift your app altogether to make some editable text control visible. If you want to achieve something specific you would need to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399153/windows-phone-7-keyboard-size), seems like there's not a good solution to dealing with the keyboard.