# How to decide touch location in silverlight WP7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there a general way to know x and y with the reference is the upper left corner of the screen?

because when I'm trying to get x and y when I'm dragging an image, I get them according to the corner of the image, not the canvas that contains the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see this.
[How do you find the screen position of a control in silverlight on WP7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740374/how-do-you-find-the-screen-position-of-a-control-in-silverlight-on-wp7)

Comment: thanks Cong Tran,, but I'm talking about silverlight, not XNA.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer