# Control.PointToScreen on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8, microsoft-metro

Is there a way to get a control's absolute screen co-ordinates on Windows Phone? also, will help if that method will work with UserControl components. WPF seems to have Control.PointToScreen, which isb't in the WP APIs

The idea is I'm trying to use a Callout control to point to a UserControl on the screen as a help bubble, and the anchor point doesn't take in absolute coordinates either - so it's a huge connected problem which I'll build up as an answer to this post.

Comment: I'm actually using transformtovisual() but i'm getting the same coordinates for all the components inside the grid. investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **UIElement.TransformToVisual()**

something like this should do the trick:

```
var control = this;    // assign the control you want to get the position of.
var transform = control.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual);
var controlPosition = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you could try `Control.MousePosition` instead

is this want you want (though it's for WP7): [How do you find the screen position of a control in silverlight on WP7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740374/how-do-you-find-the-screen-position-of-a-control-in-silverlight-on-wp7)

Comment: but I'm not using a mouse / touch, I want them to popup at the Loaded event

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood your question, probably this is what you want - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740374/how-do-you-find-the-screen-position-of-a-control-in-silverlight-on-wp7

Comment: I'll expand this post to the whole callout problem for future reference, that's still not working for me.