# How to get Screen coordinates of a control in WinRT and Silveright?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-runtime, controls

I want to get the screen coordinates (XY position) of a control in silverlight and WinRT. 
In WPF, i can get coordinates using **PointToScreen** method. But there is no similiar methods in silverlight and WinRT. 
So can anyone help me to get the screen coordinates of a control...

Comment: Does this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740374/how-do-you-find-the-screen-position-of-a-control-in-silverlight-on-wp7) help?

Comment: Yes. That works. Now i have used like below                            In WinRT, control.TransformToVisual(null).TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0))                                                                   In Silverlight, this.dataGrid.TransformToVisual(null).Transform(new Point(0, 0));                                                                                                                                                             Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. That works. Now i have used like below.
In WinRT, 
control.TransformToVisual(null).TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0)) 
In Silverlight, 
this.control.TransformToVisual(null).Transform(new Point(0, 0));